# Using URL as a condition on php

Tags: php, url, if-statement, conditional-statements

I want to show on my site an element depending on my site's url.
 Currently i have the following code:

```
<?php
   if(URL matches)
     {
     echo $something;
     }
   else
     {
     echo $otherthing;
     }
?>
```

I wanted to know how do I get the URL on the if condition, because I need to have only one php archive to show on many diferent pages

EDIT: The solution provided by Rixhers Ajazi doesnt work for me, when i use ur code i get the same URI for both of my pages, so the if sentence always goes by the else side, is any way to get the exact string u can see on the browser to the PHP code

http://img339.imageshack.us/img339/5774/sinttulocbe.png

This is the place where it changes but, the URL i get on both sides is equal, im a little bit confused

Comment: http://www.paulund.co.uk/get-current-url-with-php

Comment: use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`..

Comment: Dont know why im getting downvotes, any pointers could help me asking better for next time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the URL, use:

```
$url = http://$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Comment: using the request uri code only solved my issue thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Use following syntax with URL

```
http://mysite.com/index.php?var1=val&var2=val
```

Now you can get the values of variables in your `$_GET` variable and use in `if condition` like

```
if($_GET['var1'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by using the $_SERVER method like so :

$url = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; or $url = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];

Read up on this [more here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

```
if($url == 'WHATEVER')
     {
     echo $something;
     }
   else
     {
     echo $otherthing;
     }
?>
```

Comment: Doesn't the `echo'ed lines` need to have an ending `;`? Just saying.

Comment: My apologies, I just copied what the user put up, didn't notice the ; post updated

Comment: Yes agree completely. Thanks for catching that.

Comment: first do a var_dump of the $url to see what string is being created. If the string that is being created is the string that you want then you could do if ($url !== 'The url') { // Do something.. Then based on what you want to pass your URL  you would then add that to your $url. That is joys of working with this language you have absolute control of how you want to use curtain parts of it! Take a look at the link I posted above about the $_SERVER so you can customize it completely for yourself :) If you need more help let me know!

Answer (score 0):

You can use different variables, e.g., `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]`, or `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`. The first one contains the path after the server name and until a possible `?` in the URL (the part with the GET parameters is excluded). The second one contains also the GET parameters. You can also retrieve the hostname used to connect to the server (in case you have a virtual host situation) using `$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"]`. Therefore by concatenating all these you can reconstruct the full URL (if you really need it, maybe the script name is enough).